# Groovy script to pull the failure jobs for current date

Tags: date, groovy, jenkins

I have a written below groovy script to pull all the failed jobs from Jenkins.

`jobs_Failed = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.items.findAll{job -> job.isBuildable() && job.lastCompletedBuild && job.lastCompletedBuild.result == hudson.model.Result.FAILURE }`

This code prints failure staus of each job running a different date, but I want to fetch the failed jobs for current date alone. 
How can I add the current date to the above code?

For example:

```
Current_Output:
Jobname,StartTime,Endtime,Status
DataInsert,10/6/14 4:01:18 AM,10/6/14 5:01:18 AM, FAILED
DataDelete,10/5/14 2:01:18 AM,10/5/14 3:02:16 AM, FAILED

Accepted_Output:
Jobname,StartTime,Endtime,Status
DataInsert,10/6/14 4:01:18 AM,10/6/14 5:01:18 AM, FAILED
```

Comment: Do you want to include only failing jobs that STARTED on the current date? Or only failing jobs that ENDED on the current date? Or only jobs that did both?

Comment: The Jobs started and Failed in Current date.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the start and end datetimes to date only using:

```
String.format('%tY/%<tm/%<td', d)
```

and then compare them to:

```
def today = new Date()
todaydate = String.format('%tY/%<tm/%<td', today)
```